# How to make a form save to the database every time it is edited in Django?

Tags: django, asynchronous

So I am trying to replicate the Google Docs functionality wherein every time you edit, the document will be saved. Will I be putting an `onchange` function on every input in the form then sending the data through ajax? How should I approach this or is this even feasible?

Note: I am just asking for some sort of pseudocode or simply the flow-chart of how I should do things.

Answer (score 1):

I think that something like this should works:

```
jQuery(function($){

   function changeFn(){
     // make ajax save.
   } 


   var timer;

   $("#doc").bind("keyup", function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(changeFn, 2000)
   });

});
```

This will wait 2 seconds(you can try with 3 - 5 seconds) after the user press the last key, then will call the ajax function to save the content. I think that is better than save all the time when the user press a key. Note that if the user press a key before that time, the timeout will be interrupted and will initiate a new count.